# Get datatables absolute row index, not current page row index?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables 1.10.4. I'm trying to get the row number of a datatables row I have selected irrespective of the page.  I use this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.someclickedelement', function () 
{ 
    var rowNumber = jQuery(this).parents("tr:first")[0].rowIndex;
});
```

This gives me the correct row index if my datatable is listing all the rows at once on one page.  But if it is listing in pages rowNumber is relative to the current page, not the first page.  How do I fix this?  How do I get rowIndex relative to the start of the entire table, even if I'm clicking rows on like page 5 or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();   
$('#example').on('click', 'td', function(){
   var index = $('#example').DataTable()
       .rows({ search: 'applied'})
       .nodes()
       .to$()
       .index($(this).closest('tr'));

   alert(index);      
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygccxq4e/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect.

Comment: @KenWilliams accept this answer if this is what you needed

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.